# How to conver OLE/BLOB into Text format in MS ACCESS

Tags: database, ms-access, blob, oledb

I am doing a POC using a tool. To save my works I am using is MS ACCESS mdb file (sample db file). The content/objects I given in tool are saved in table format in mdb file. I am giving some sentence or paragraph in my tool designer which is saved as a OLE/BLOB format. When I open the mdb file I can see the content as "long binary data" in that particular column. I want to retrieve those content into text format. How to convert a OLE/BLOB object into text format? Is there any specific query is available? How to update those content if I want to update with or without converting the data from BLOB to text format?

Comment: You really can't answer that question without specifiying how you stored it exactly. A binary blob says you stored a file in your database. How you can read the text out of that file is dependent on the file type.

Comment: I want to extract the content which is stored as 'long binary data' in MS ACCESS to my local machine. Any suggestion?

Comment: Well, I just suggested you tell me the actual file type. Long binary data contains a file, and dependent on the type of file, it might be easy or it might be hard. It might be, for example, a Word document, or an ANSI text file, or an UTF-8 text file. Without knowing the file type of the file stored in that binary data, I can't answer it

Comment: Even I am not sure about what type of file it is. First I need to extract the content to local after that only I can able to tell you what type of file it is.

Comment: Well, then start by figuring that out. As said, dependent on the file type, the way to get the text varies. You can try [OLEToDisk](http://www.lebans.com/oletodisk.htm) by Stephen Lebans to export the file